# Hide register/login page if user is logged in? Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have create my login in codeigniter using sessions and whenever i try to add if statements to hide register page and login page from nav bar once user is logged in it does not seem to work. This below is my navigation menu code and i was wondering just exactly where and how would i write down statement to hide the register and login page once user is logged in?

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
   <li class="nav-item active ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item active ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php/user/account">Account</a>
   </li>
   <?php if($this->session->userdata('username')) : ?>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php/user">Login</a>
   </li>
   <?php if($this->session->userdata('username')) : ?>
   <li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="index.php/registerPage">Register</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

I know the sessions is working as whenever i go back to login it redirects me to account page which then gives me option to logout and also show login details. just not sure how to put it in this navigation menu.

Comment: Hi, you should put the code with the `if` statement so we may figure out if something wrong.

Comment: @ankabot i have updated my code.

Comment: @ankabot how could i instead make a header page to use navigation menu on all pages? this way i think i could make use of sessions instead of just putting this in on each nav bar on each pages?

Comment: it's seems to me `if(!$this->session->userdata('username'))` see the `!` for negation. Also don't forget the `endif;` to close the `if` block. You should not repeat the menu's code in every page, you would rather put the menu's code in a file and use [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to include this file in every file (view) that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

you have a mistake on your **if statement** here i have updated your code.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url();?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
<?php 
//here we check if session `username` is exist. so it means that the current user is logged in correctly
if($this->session->userdata('username')) : ?>
            <li class="nav-item active ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/user/account'); ?>">Account</a>
            </li>
<?php else : ?>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/user'); ?>">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo site_url('/registerPage'); ?>">Register</a>
            </li>
<?php endif;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry took long time reply. It now says: Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$session  . I have removed session from autoload. and put it back there but still same message.?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
if (isset($this->session->userdata['username'])) {

    $message= '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item active ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home <span 
             class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php/user/account">Account</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>';

    } else {
        $message = '<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item active ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home 
               <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php/user/account">Account</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php/user">Login</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item ">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php/registerPage">Register</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>';}
 echo ($message);
```